# Making a simple directive only modal dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i am a new to angular. Trying to make a simple modal using angular directives only.
The reasons for making this:

1. **No** need to use **bootstrap**
2. **No** need for a **controller** and
3. Thus **no dependency injection**

   ```
           function modalTrigger() {
               return {
                   restrict: 'A',
                   transclude: true,
                   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                       scope.show = false;
                       scope.toggleModal = function() {
                           console.log(scope);
                           scope.show = !scope.show;
                       };
                   },
                   template: '<div class="modal-trigger" ng-click="toggleModal()" ng-transclude></div>'
               };
           }

           function modalDialog() {
                   return {
                       restrict: 'E',
                       transclude: true,
                       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                           scope.dialogStyle = {};
                           if (attrs.width)
                               scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
                           if (attrs.height)
                               scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
                           scope.hideModal = function() {
                               console.log("called hide modal");
                               scope.show = false;
                           };
                       },
                       template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='modal-backdrop' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='container' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'><a href=''>&times;</a></div><div class='modal-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
                   };
               }
   ```

"modal-trigger" directive is used to trigger the "modal-dialog" directive by setting "show" to true. here are the two directives

Right now, if you click any of the triggers, both the modals show up. how do i make the triggers specific to their own modals?

To make things more clear, here is an example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNwTy3ddFFBBm2DPHUGA?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both modals observe the same attribute (`show`) for showing/hiding themselves. To correct this, the `show` attribute must be scoped for each modal and I propose the following:

1. Have a controller that defines the 2 show attributes:

   ```
   app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.show1 = false;
       $scope.show2 = false;
   });
   ```

   And activate it as:

   ```
   <body ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
   ```
2. Change the modal trigger to have isolated scope and the `show` attribute, as follows:

   ```
   function modalTrigger() {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           transclude: true,
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               scope.toggleModal = function() {
                   scope.show = !scope.show;
               };
           },
           scope: {
             show: '='
           },
           template: '<div class="modal-trigger" ng-click="toggleModal()" ng-transclude></div>'
       };
   }
   ```

   Use it e.g. as:

   ```
   <a href="" data-modal="modal1" modal-trigger show="ctrl.show1">Waiting List</a>
   ```
3. Change the modal directive to use isolated scope with the `show` attribute; simply add:

   ```
           scope: {
             show: '='
           },
   ```

   to the directive. Use it as:

   ```
   <modal-dialog data-modal-name="modal1" show="ctrl.show1">
   ```

A forked plunker with the full solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/cJOXju9H3PMjRdUKqVCF?p=preview

Comment: Brilliant answer! but is there any way we can eliminate the use of controllers? this is because i will have a few modals common in the layout. So if we use the controller, we will have to initialise that in the layout itself. also, another purpose was that just editing the view would give a new modal, without touching the controller!

Comment: The controller here is just a container for the `show` properties. You can place them wherever you want in your application and they can be made reusable. If not for the `show` properties, how else will you relate the modal to its trigger?

Comment: A (dirty in my opinion) way to create `show` flags by only touching the view is the `ng-init="showX = false"` directive. (e.g. [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/IT34hBoBa04H1f4OdP6W?p=preview) - note that the properties **HAVE** to be placed under an object for the 2-way binding to work properly)